# Consider the autonomus equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=-2(y-1)(y-2)(y-a)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the autonomus equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=-2(y-1)(y-2)(y-a)^2$, where $a$ is any real number.

Then,

$(1)$ Plot the phase diagram showing the solution curves.

$(2)$ show that new solution can be generated from the old solutions (in $(a)$) by **time shifting** i.e, replacing $y(t)$ by $y(t-t_0)$.

**Answer:**

$(a)$ I have drawn the phase plot showing the solutions.

Please help me with the part $(b)$.

If we replace $y(t)$ by $y(t-t_0)$, then we have

$\frac{dy(t-t_0)}{dt}=-2(y(t-t_0)-1)(y(t-t_0)-2)(y(t-t_0)-a)^2$.

How to confirm that we get a new solution?

Help me

$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy(t-t_0)}{dt}=-2(y(t-t_0)-1)(y(t-t_0)-2)(y(t-t_0)-a)^2$$
Change of variable : $\quad\theta=t-t_0$ :
$$\frac{dy(\theta)}{dt}=-2(y(\theta)-1)(y(\theta)-2)(y(\theta)-a)^2.$$
$d\theta=dt$
$$\frac{dy(\theta)}{d\theta}=-2(y(\theta)-1)(y(\theta)-2)(y(\theta)-a)^2.$$
Thus $y(\theta)$ is solution of the ODE.

Since $y(\theta)=y(t-t_0)$ this proves that $y(t-t_0)$ is also solution.